# Replacing multiple if statements

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-cmdlet

I am using PS version 5.0 and I have quite a few `if` statements which might grow over time.

```
if ($hostname -like "**12*") {
    Write-Output "DC1"
} elseif ($Hostname -like "**23*") {
    Write-Output "DC2"
} elseif ($Hostname -like "**34*") {
    Write-Output "DC3"
} elseif ($Hostname -like "**45*") {
    Write-Output "DC4"
}
```

Can you suggest some better way of writing the same code?

Comment: can you please suggest how the switch statement will look like here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-5.0) statement. Here is an example using the `-Regex` flag since it looks like you are doing just a simple match and then could cut out the `*` wildcards.

```
$hostname = 'asdf12asdf'
switch -Regex ($hostname) {
    "12" {Write-Output "DC1"}
    "23" {Write-Output "DC2"}
    "34" {Write-Output "DC3"}
    "45" {Write-Output "DC4"}
    Default {Write-Error "No Match Found"}
}
```

If you didn't want multiple matches add a `; Break` after each case. For example if you had a host name such as `asdf12asdf34` a statement `"12" {Write-Output "DC1"; Break}` would prevent the output both of `12` and `34`